# How to check the Support Library / AppCompat library version at Runtime?

Tags: android, runtime, version, android-support-library, android-appcompat

We have an SDK for Android that requires Support Library v4 with targetSdk 23 (meaning that the Support Library should be also 23). For commercial reasons, I have to  upgrade the SDK so it should work even if the App is compiled against API 21.

This means that some calls to the Support Library should be done conditionally depending on the current Support Library version of the App (**not the current API level**), so I have 3 options here (ranked by best to worst):

1 - Check the Support Library version before the method call (This is what I have not figured out how to do, (if possible at all)).
2 - Use reflection.
3 - Use Try Catch blocks.

So for the 1st option, is it possible to check the support library version at runtime?

Comment: The support library does not expose any API for obtaining version information and, generally speaking, is not designed to support what you are trying to accomplish. There's also no reason you would need to use v23 of the support library if you're using targetSdk 23.

Comment: @alanv This code is for an SDK not for an App which changes the rules a little bit. Think that this code should run if you have AppCompatV4 revision 21 or revision 23. There are some methods that are not available in the revision 21 because were introduced in revision 23, so I need to be sure under which version the code is running to avoid crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my question with the approach I finally chose:

It is not possible to check the Support Library / AppCompat library revisions at Runtime.
Typically you already know which version of the Support Library / AppCompat Library version you are going to use, as it is declared explicitly in the App dependencies. However, due that in this case the **SDK code should run under any condition** (or at least a min version of the libraries), some different things were done in order to solve the problem:

1 - Check method availability using Java Reflection.
2 - Invoke methods using also reflection and `try-catch` blocks (in order to ensure App stability)
3 - Determine the AppCompat version using the info provided by the `catch` block.
4 - Subsequent calls don't use reflection as existence of the methods has been already checked, and min version has been already found.